# How to deserialize an object with class string value

Tags: c#, json-deserialization

I am querying a table, it has 2 columns. First one is a json string, second is the string class name.

Typically to deserialize an object I would do the follow

```
var newObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObject>(jsonString);
```

But in this case, I only have a string value of MyObject. I'm wondering, how can I deserialize this object?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to get the `Type` from that string value:

```
Type type = Type.GetType(typeName);
```

Then use the `DeserializeObject` overload that takes a `Type` parameter:

```
var newObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString, type);
```

See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject_2.htm.

Comment: Thank you, you're a life saver!